# Want to get the common parameter from URL itself even if proxy get change

Tags: java, proxy

I want to get the host name and host port from http request i.e from  http://101.101.101.11:8080/abc.html

I can get these paramater of URL by httpRequest.gethostname() or request.getserverport()

but when I am acccessing that URL through proxy that time the host name and server port is getting change.

If I use Referer that time I am getting perfect host name and server port. But it is kind of header parameter with that URL. And I need some parameter from URL itself.

Is there any way to get the common parameter from URL itself even if proxy get change.

Thanks very much in advance

Comment: Which `getHostname()` method do you mean? AFAIK there is none in `HttpServletRequest`. Besides that the problem is that the proxy will act as the server's client so it might call a totally different url. The only way to get the original values I know of is via header fields (if they are set by the proxy).

Comment: I was talking about String scheme = request.getScheme();
String serverName = request.getServerName();
int serverPort = request.getServerPort();
String contextPath = request.getContextPath();